# Are Photos from the Photos app in iOS backed up to iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos.app

Are Photos from the Photos app in iOS backed up to iCloud? I basically make albums in iPhoto and they are saved in my Photos app on my device. I really hope these are getting backed up to iCloud. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 1000 photos and 30 days are, via the photo stream. Apple details [here](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html). But this should be seen as a temporary solution.